# django processing dynamic html elements

Tags: jquery, django, dynamic-data

i create the html items dynamically with Django.

```
{% for scraper in scrapers %}
<div class='scraper_item'>
        <ul class="scraper_actions1">
        <li><a href="/schedule/{{ scraper.id }}">Schedule</a></li>
        <li><a class="delete" id="{{ scraper.id }}" href="/delete/{{scraper.id}}">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I pass 'scrapers' as the model objects into html page and list them. I want to process each object selected by id with the same jQuery function. How can i do selection of a particular element to pass it to Django views `def delete(request, scraper_id)` without multiply coding?

```
$("a.delete").click(function(event){
        alert("going to delete...");
                    ...???
            return false;    
        });
```

Comment: Do you ask how to find the ids of the elements or you wonder how to send a jQuery request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code to find an 'id' attribute of an element:

```
$( event.target ).attr( 'id' )
```

[More info](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).